# Cuda Toolkit directory does not exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have a problem with cuda 4.1 and visual studio 2010.
When I want to compile a .cu-file I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.1.targets(249,9): error : The CUDA Toolkit  directory '' does not exist.  Please verify the CUDA Toolkit is installed properly or define the CudaToolkitDir property to resolve this error.
```

I got a clean windows 7 install with only vs2010, CUDA Toolkit v4.1 and the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK (and git) running inside a VirtualBox.

I tried to specify the toolkit directory in the project properties in "CUDA Toolkit Custom Dir", but that doesn't make any difference. Even in a completely new VBox this error occurs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got the same error in our build server (Jenkins) after updating CUDA. All I had to do was restart the server...

Answer (score 7):

OK, I got it myself: The project I used was set up with cuda 4.0 and it did not update correctly as I installed v4.1.
To update it just disable and enable "CUDA 4.1(.targets, .props)" in the Custom Build Steps.

Comment: Hi, I'm seeing the same problem. by 'To update it just disable and enable "CUDA 4.1(.targets, .props)" in the Custom Build Steps.' do you mean uncheck cuda 4.0 and check CUD 4.1? In my case, my old project from VS2010 was using CUD 4.0 and custom build is set to use CUDA 4.0 but I still see that message.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same with Cuda 9.1 on VS 2017. What solved it for me was to set the 
"CUDA Toolkit Custom Dir"to be the same as CUDA_PATH. see in the following link:
https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/3.2/Content/CUDA_Properties_Config.htm
in Common section, item #1.

Comment: Your post gave me the clue I needed (so have an upvote, even though you aren't addressing the original poster's actual question).  Presumably you (like me) just upgraded from Cuda 9.0 to 9.1.  In that case, the "better" fix is to go to Solution Explorer, right click on the project and choose "Build Dependencies" then "Build Customizations".  From here, uncheck the (now uninstalled) Cuda 9.0 and check Cuda 9.1.

Comment: To add: You can also set the property as simply $(CUDA_PATH) . Visual Studio will expand it to the environment variable, which is (usually?) added when you install the toolkit   This was also the correct fix for me (Cuda 10.0, VS 2017), so have another upvote :)